# How Process Azure Analysis Services on SSMS Job

Tags: service, ssms, analysis, azure-analysis-services

I currently have this flow

local DB source -> Azure Datawarehouse -> Azure Analysis Service Model (deployed via Visual Studio 2019).

I'm wondering whether there's a way to create and schedule a job on the local DB in order to refresh the Azure Analysis Service.

I've seen some posts where you can achieve this in Azure itself through functions. However, I was wondering whether I can do it on SSMS.

**UPDATE**
I created a linked server on my localhost DB to the Azure Analysis Services. I created a SQL Agent Job with the below code:

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "automatic",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "test",
        "table": "DimCustomer"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*I get this error:*
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. System.ArgumentException: Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available.   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Xmla.ConnectionInfo.SetConnectionString(String cs)   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Olap.SoapClient.Connect()   at OlapEvent(SCH_STEP* pStep, SUBSYSTEM* pSubSystem, SUBSYSTEMPARAMS* pSubSystemParams, Boolean fQueryFlag).  The step failed.

Is this error caused because I created the linked server in my localhost DB and the analysis services is retrieving data from the Azure DB?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about a SQL Agent job. If so you can create a SQL Server linked server to connect to Azure Analysis Services and let you run a TMSL refresh command. The documentation of a sample is [here](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/README.md#linkedserver) and the sample code is [here](https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/LinkedServer/SQL%20Linked%20Server%20to%20Azure%20Analysis%20Services.sql). See the last `exec` command.

Comment: I tried that. I updated my question with what I've tried

Comment: @Camus what version of SQL Server? Can you script out your linked server so we can compare the options? Did you run the stored proc sp_addlinkedsrvlogin which associates a login? Can you share that code (minus the password)?